# Spring InternalResourceViewResolver not using WEB-INF as root for viewing

Tags: spring, jsp, path

My web application uses root path starting from Tomcat's /webapps/ folder as application root and not WEB-INF folder. Can anyone show me where my configuration is wrong?

Difficulty: it's quite confusing because going to index page works OK. What's is also confusing is that RequestMapping works OK, I can see Hibernate making SQL queries which means that autowired Service (and Repository) are called OK.

Here are my configuration files:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>city-http</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/city-http-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>city-http</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

city-http-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:integ="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="nikzgs.city.app" />   

    <!-- Maps a logical view name to a physical resource -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
         <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1900000" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- -->
    <bean id="jdbcPropertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" 
        p:username="${jdbc.username}" 
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:persistence.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="entityManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

IndexController which works OK:

```
package nikzgs.city.app.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

index.jsp under /WEB-INF/jsp/ folder displayed OK:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Index page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Welcome!</h3>
    <a href="${contextPath}/city/viewList">View cities</a>
    <br />
    <a href="/city/viewList">View cities without context path</a>
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

CityController:

```
package nikzgs.city.app.controller;

import java.util.List;

import nikzgs.city.app.entity.City;
import nikzgs.city.app.service.CityService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/city")
public class CityController {

    @Autowired
    private CityService cityService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/viewList",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String cityViewForm(Model model) {
        return prepareCityListForReview(model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addNewCity",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addNewCity(@ModelAttribute("newCity") City newCity, Model model) {
        cityService.addCity(newCity);
        return prepareCityListForReview(model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/editCity","/modifyCity"},  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewEditCityForm(@ModelAttribute("cityUnderEdit") City cityUnderEdit, @RequestParam("id")Long id, Model model) {
        if (null != id) {
            City cityToEdit = cityService.getCityById(id);
            model.addAttribute("cityUnderEdit", cityToEdit);
        }
        return "city/cityEdit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateCity",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateCity(@ModelAttribute("cityUnderEdit") City cityUnderEdit, Model model) {
        cityService.updateCity(cityUnderEdit);
        return prepareCityListForReview(model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteCity",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteCity(@RequestParam("id")Long id, Model model) {
        if (null != id) {
            cityService.deleteCityById(id);
        }
        return prepareCityListForReview(model);
    }

    private String prepareCityListForReview(Model model) {
        List<City> cities = cityService.getAllCities();
        model.addAttribute("cities", cities);
        model.addAttribute("newCity", new City());
        return "city/cityList";
    }
}
```

Also, 2 screenshots with URL and folder structure, I believe they will be helpful[image: wrong path]

Index OK:

[image: index ok]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
<property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
```

to

```
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
```

Also use the JSTL core tag lib's `<c:url value='/some-path'/>` to output correct URLs